# Android Emulator Wont Show my App, only the lock screen

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, development-environment

I have a problem regarding my emulator. (I have a Mac)

I'm using Eclipse with ADT and created the simple Hello World application, and when I run the project, Eclipse launches the Android emulator with the screen saying "ANDROID" and everything is normal. But after a few minutes, instead of showing my program (or app), the android emulator will go to the lock screen or main screen of the cell phone and NOT my app.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Unlock the screen?

The emulator is a direct emulation of an Android device so you have to interactive with it as such.
i.e unlock the lock screen and you will see your app